# Using an already existing HTML as a Jekyll post

Tags: jekyll

I have just started creating a website with Jekyll. I have some html pages I already generated with Rmarkdown inside R. The computations take a while and I would prefer to make the html document separate then upload them as posts into the website.

When I put the front matter in, it screws up the post, so how do I put the except and title and such? And then, oddly, when I take the front matter out, the post doesn't revert to the way it was before.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you give us an example? This shouldn't happen, and is even documented as something you should be able to do: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/#custom-variables. If you could give us a [mcve], this could help.

Comment: Hey thanks. I actually figured out that something was getting messed up when I went to edit the html file directly from github. Your post helped because it let me know that what I was doing was right there was something else unrelated that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was not not waiting long enough for github to load the file before I started editing it. It works if I edit from vi then upload.